# How do I determine if a specific port is open for incoming traffic behind firewall

Tags: android

I am trying to stream audio using Android's MediaPlayer library.

In some cases, the stream URL is of an unusual port. For example, `http://203.150.225.77:8400`. If I were to try and access this stream from  behind a firewall in my browser, it gives me an "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to `203.150.225.77:8400`" error.

Frrom media player in my android device, I get : `MusicStream(1806): Media Player Error: Stream URL Invalid (1) -1004`

At the moment, I'm just handling this exception. However, I would like to be able to pre-test the URL to determine if the stream is available before starting the MediaPlayer.

So, I created an function to test the url using HttpURLConnection as follows:

```
protected int isURLValid(MusicStream streamInstance, String urlString)
{
    streamInstance.timeout = 0;
    int success = 0;
    try
    {

        URL url;
        url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);
        urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
        new Thread(new InterruptThread(Thread.currentThread(), urlConnection,streamInstance)).start();

        if (streamInstance.timeout == 0)
        {
            success = 1;
        }

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("MusicStream", "MalformedURLException");
        Log.w("MusicStream", e);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("MusicStream", "IOException");
        Log.w("MusicStream", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.exception = e;
        Log.w("MusicStream", "Exception");
        Log.w("MusicStream", e);

    }


    return success;

}
```

As you can see in the above code, I start a new thread to timeout after 5000ms. Here is my thread:

```
public class InterruptThread implements Runnable {
    Thread parent;
    URLConnection con;
    MusicStream streamInstance;

    public InterruptThread(Thread parent, URLConnection con, MusicStream streamInstance) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.con = con;
        this.streamInstance = streamInstance;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        Log.d("MusicStream", "Timer thread forcing parent to quit connection");
        ((HttpURLConnection)con).disconnect();
        Log.d("MusicStream","Timer thread closed connection held by parent, exiting");
        streamInstance.timeout = 1;
    }
}
```

Nontheless, when I reference my function:

```
if (isURLValid(streamInstance[0],streamURL) == 1){
    // Valid URL!
    Log.d("MusicStream", "The stream is valid!");
    this.ResultString = streamURL;
    streamInstance[0].setFirewallError(MusicStream.GONE,streamURL);
}
else{
    // Streaming URL invalid. 
    // Firewall Error
    errorCode = MusicStream.FIREWALL_ERROR;
    Log.d("MusicStream", "The stream is not valid!");
    streamInstance[0].setFirewallError(MusicStream.VISIBLE,streamURL);
}
```

the log output is as follows

```
A stream has been supplied: http://203.150.225.77:8400
The stream is valid!
MusicStream(1806): Media Player Error: Stream URL Invalid (1) -1004
```

As soon as I switch my device from Wireless to 3G, the streaming works, so I'm a bit at a loss as to why my url-checking mechanism is coming back with a valid when behind the firewall. Can anyone see any reason as to why my check comes back valid, and possibly make a suggestion as to how I can check the status in a more foolproof way?

Extra Thought: I was thinking that maybe some firewalls will respond with a "blocked" page, in which case getting the header won't work. However, this is not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't deal with all content, but I found that streams behind firewalls *were* returning valid html headers. The headers seen were as follows:

Behind Firewall:

```
Content Length:     3469
Content Encoding:   null
Content Type:       text/html
Content Expiration: 0
Content Date:       1381912000000
```

On a different device, I received a null response:

```
Content Length:     -1
Content Encoding:   null
Content Type:       null
Content Expiration: 0
Content Date:       0
```

A valid stream that wasn't behind a firewall returned an mpeg header. note content type and length:

```
Content Length:     -1
Content Encoding:   null
Content Type:       audio/mpeg
Content Expiration: 0
Content Date:       0
```

To check my url, I'm just resorted to checking that the content type and length are as expected for an audio stream.